# How to ignore library project from Git pull?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git

I am a newbie in dealing with Git. I am using Git in eclipse.

My main project contains the `google-play-services_lib` has a library project.

Recently I did `Git -> Fetch` from remote repository and now when I do `Git -> Pull` in main project, I get conflicts in `google-play-services_lib` which I never changed (generated files changes).

I want to ignore the library project changes from Git pull in eclipse.

Whenever I take Git pull from main Project, I always get the following conflict in eclipse-

```
Checkout conflict with files: 


google-play-services_lib/bin/AndroidManifest.xml
google-play-services_lib/bin/R.txt
google-play-services_lib/bin/google-play-services_lib.jar
google-play-services_lib/bin/jarlist.cache
```

So though these conflicts are system generated changes, I always want to ignore them.

I used `Team -> Disconnect` on  `google-play-services_lib`, but this only disconnected me from Git for the library `google-play-services_lib`.

I used `Team -> Ignore` on  `google-play-services_lib`, but this did nothing in resolving conflicts.

I used `Team -> Untrack` on  `google-play-services_lib`, but this added all files in `google-play-services_lib` in the conflict state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Options `Assume unchanged` and `Assume changed`:

- Assume Unchanged to all of the generated files
- Pull
- Assume Changed to all the generated files

Because this will get very annoying if you have to do it for every commit, you could write a Script to handle this. The required commands are:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

Comment: I did what you mentioned in my library project. But Pull is still giving me conflicts. Please note that I already did `Git -> Fetch` from remote repository. May be this is the problem ?

Comment: Right click the dirty files → Replace with → HEAD Revision if that is what you need